# Show that the sequence of functions is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2[0, 1]$ but not in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function, cauchy-problem

The problem is to show that the sequence of functions  $f_n(t) = 
$ \begin{cases} 
      0 & 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{n}\\
      \frac{1}{2}+\frac{n(t-\frac{1}{2})}{2}& \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{n} < t < \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{n} \\
      1 & \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq 1
   \end{cases}

is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2[0, 1]$ but not in C[0,1] (i.e., using the uniform norm).

$\\$

I have proved that in for continuous function [0,1] it is not Cauchy:

Let $m \leq n$, consider $|| f_m(x) - f_n(x)||$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $||f_n(x)|| \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ where $x = \frac{1}{2}$. And since the function becomes an uncontinuous fucntion, it is not Cauchy.

But for the $L^2[0,1]$ space, I know $||f_m(x) - f_n(x)||_2 = =\int_{0}^1 (f_m(x) - f_n(x))^2dx$. I don't know how should I proceed.

Can anyone help me to check if for $C[0,1]$ is a right aprroach and how to check for $L^2[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

let be $n\geq 1$, we have:

$$
\lVert f_{2n} - f_{n}\rVert_{\infty} \geq \left| f_{2n}\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}\right)
-f_n\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}\right)\right| = \frac{1}{4}
$$
so $f_n$ is not Cauchy in $C^{\infty}[0,1]$

Let be $h\in L^2[0,1]$:
$$h(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2}\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

we have
$$ \lVert f_m - f_n\rVert  \leq \lVert f_m - h\rVert + \lVert f_n - h\rVert$$

so it suffice to prove $\lVert f_n - h\rVert_{L^2} \to 0$

**P.S.**: we have to prove $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$, but we know that $L^2$ is complete, so it is natural to search for an $h$ s.t. $\lVert f_n - h \rVert_{L^2} \to 0$